# View a multipage TIFF in Javascript

Tags: javascript, tiff

I currently have multi-paged `TIFF` images and I need to browse them page by page via Javascript.

I have no clue about that. Can you help me? I found some other questions but none seems related to Javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt JavaScript can help you here: Most browsers can't deal with TIFF images in the first place, let alone multi-page ones.

You will need the help of server-side scripting - like PHP - in combination with a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).

I've never tried this myself, but IM's multipage syntax seems to be pretty straightforward:

```
# extract page 15 from tiff file

convert 'image.tif[15]' image-15.jpg
```

note that if your TIFF is in [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK)  format, you will need to perform an additional colour space conversion to RGB - Internet Explorer can't deal with CMYK images in any format.

Comment: Looks like I definitely need server help, maybe with AJAX. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I ported the LibTIFF library to Javascript with Emscripten (https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js).
This page (http://seikichi.github.io/tiff.js/multipage.html) is the demo of multipage tiff file.

Comment: That's the toughest code I have ever seen. How was it even possible to build something like that? Hat's off mate. Great Job!

Answer (score 2):

There are plugin that provide those function.  [Alternatiff](http://www.alternatiff.com/)  is a good example.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The original project no longer seems to be maintained (thanks Victoria!), but both tiff.js by GPHelmley and seikichi's libTiff port mentioned in their answer have active forks; see

https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/network

and

https://github.com/GPHemsley/tiff-js/network

**Original**

A new, **native JavaScript** tiff approach has appeared since the last round of answers:
[tiff.js](https://github.com/GPHemsley/tiff-js), with comments on multi-page tiff support [here](https://github.com/GPHemsley/tiff-js/issues/12) (apparently added in to [pdf.js](https://github.com/GPHemsley/pdf.js) though I haven't checked it out).

I found that for my case it was easy to hack the tiff.js code to allow loading multipage tiffs really easily, and plan to contribute the hack to the tiff.js repo.

Comment: tiff.js seems to be dead. No updates in 3 years. Sad.

Comment: @Victoria - yes, unfortunately the same seems to be true of the libtiff port by seikichi (no activity in almost 2 years): however both projects have active  forks... I just haven't looked into them yet to be able to provide good info. Thanks for pointing it out though, I'll add a note

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with a certain plugin technology (namely Silverlight or Moonlight), you can use the free [LibTiff .NET](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library to process and display most kinds of TIFF files client-side.