# How to show multiple page `.tif` file on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, tiff

My requirement is to show `.tiff` image on browser. So currently I'm showing `tiff` file on Internet Explore using `img` tag like below.

```
<img src="myTiff.tif" type="image/tiff" alt="My Tiff">
```

And it works perfect with the tif file having only single page. In case there would an multiple pages in `.tif` then the `img` tag only shows 1st image. User can not get option to view other image.

[**Sample tiff image**](https://bz.apache.org/ooo/attachment.cgi?id=3581)

I already tried all the option suggested [**here**](http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html)

I'm using C# on server side & on front end using AngularJS. Any help would appreciated. Thanks :)

**Edit**

Would it be better way to go with **AltraTiff** plugin? I looks like working on Internet Explorer.

Comment: Can you use google docs ?

Comment: You will not avoid using a plugin unless you split the tiff. End of story.

Comment: Especially http://stackoverflow.com/a/19899703/295783 works

Comment: @MairajAhmad No i can't use google docs..i want to show it on the browser itself

Comment: @mplungjan I can't use that..could i know why image tag is only showing 1st page..why It wont show multiple page..

Comment: The img tag is only meant to show one image.

Comment: @mplungjan let me try the plugin which you has suggested..that looks like I need to only add javascript..Thanks for link

Comment: Ouch. The JavaScript Works in Chrome, but does not seem to work in IE

Comment: @mplungjan my first requirement is that it should work in Internet Explorer

Comment: I know. I think you might be -SOL- unable to use only the client. As suggested, request it page per page using a link to the server

Comment: You can split the frames of tiff image on server side and display them based on the frame number.

Comment: @MairajAhmad Any reference link would be better to proceed my work. Thanks for your time..

Comment: @mplungjan could you suggest me some plugin that would work on IE browswer?

Comment: @pankajparkar Have a look at this http://www.davidloo.com/?p=15

Comment: @Robert Thanks..any link for the same would appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

Content rendering is always browser's responsibility so you rely in its capabilities.

Maybe there is some plugin for some browser that supports multiple-page tiffs, but, if you can't control software installed in your clients, I think your best option would be to implement some pagination by separating pages server side.

You can achieve that easily with imagemagick.

The only drawback is that, if user try to download it, it will download only the single page he were currently viewing.

But yo can mitigate it by providing separate download link or, simply, linking full version to the displayed image. Example using jQuery:

```
<div id="tiffPager">
    <a href="myTiff.tif">
        <img width=200 height=200 data-pageCount=5 src="myTiff_page0.tif" alt="My Tiff">
    </a>
    <button class="pageBack">&lt;&lt;</button>
    <button class="pageForward">&gt;glt;</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var container = $("div#tiffPager");
        var img = $("img", container);
        var backBtn = $("button.pageBack", container);
        var fwBtn = $("button.pageForward", container);
        var pgCount = img.data("pageCount");
        var currPage = 0;

        backBtn.on("click", function(){
            currPage = (currPage + 1) % pgCount; // Cycle though pages.
            img.attr("src", "myTiff_page" + currPage + ".tif");
        });
        fwBtn.on("click", function(){
            currPage = (currPage - 1) % pgCount; // Cycle though pages.
            img.attr("src", "myTiff_page" + currPage + ".tif");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you have anyother alternative..please suggest. :(

Comment: You said you "don't wanted to use third party PLUGIN", nothing about javascript and, by the way, @mplungjan and me answered you: Unless in corporate environment where you could decide about every client software, you CAN'T control how clients render any content type. Some could use some plugin wich allows tiff pagination, but most of them won't. Also you could wait about a decade and check again... Maybe then you get luck ;-)

Comment: @bitfet yes you are correct..I should have end up with the plugin..does `imagemagick` support in `.Net` or should I refer a different plugin

Comment: I don't know. I usually use console executable to generate files in some temporary directory. Then you can use them as cache by comparing it's mtime with the original image one and, optionally, remove ones whith too long atime.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help & time..+1 for your help.